# Get first 3 sections of IP address

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to do a very simple task that would be trivial for me in any other language, and I can't make it happen in R.

I want the first 3 sections of an IP. So, `192.168.0.1` becomes `192.168.0`. How should I go about this?

I've tried the regex route...

```
grep('[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.', '192.168.0.1', value = TRUE)
```

This gives me the full IP address, though.

I've tried a function that I could then lapply over my list of IPs...

```
ip_start <- function(ip) {
  if (is.na(ip) | ip == '' | ip == ' ') {
    return(na)
  } else {
    sections = strsplit(ip,'\\.')
    return(paste(sections[[1]][1], sections[[1]][2], sections[[1]][3], sep = '.'))
  }
}

test <- lapply(full_data$IPAD, ip_start)
```

This is gives me...

```
Error in strsplit(ip, "\\.") : non-character argument
```

I can't figure out why this would be the case. The only data I have are IP addresses or a single blank space.

Thoughts?

Comment: how your actual input looks like?

Comment: A list of IPV4 addresses...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use [**`sub`**](http://rfunction.com/archives/2354) to replace the last `.` and following digits.

```
x <- c('192.168.0.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.0.1')
sub('\\.\\d+$', '', x)
# [1] "192.168.0" "192.168.1" "192.168.0"
```

Otherwise, if you want to return NA for invalid or empty matches, I suppose you could do ...

```
x <- c('192.168.0.1', '192.168.1.1', "don't use me.3", ' ')
r <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('^(\\d+\\.){2}\\d+', x))
unlist({r[sapply(r, length)==0] <- NA; r})
# [1] "192.168.0" "192.168.1" NA          NA
```

Comment: You would fail this one: c('192.168.0.1', "don't use me.3", " " , '192.168.1.1', '192.168.0.1')

Comment: Still seems to return the full string if no match is found. I'd use stringr's str_match(x,'\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}')[,1]

Comment: the OP seems to attempt to return NA in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regmatches` and `gregexpr` functions.

```
> x <- '192.168.0.1'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<!\\.)[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+(?=\\.\\d+)", x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "192.168.0"
```

**OR**

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "192.168.0"
```

This would fetch only the first three parts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `strsplit` solution:

```
x <- '192.168.0.1'
paste(strsplit(x, '[.]')[[1]][-4], collapse='.')
## [1] "192.168.0"
```

This handles `x` of length 1 only.  To extend this, you can use `Vectorize` or an explicit `*apply`:

```
sapply(x, function(x) paste(strsplit(x, '[.]')[[1]][-4], collapse='.'))
```